# Get a list of lists out of a Python object

Tags: python, list, object

I have an object called Language:

```
class Language():
    niceGreetings = ["Hello", "Hi"]
    referToSelf = ["Me", "I"]
    referToCollective = ["We", "Us"]
    referToObject = ["The","It"]
    travelPastTense = ["Went"]
    directionNonSpecific = ["To", "From"]
```

I want to get a function that does this, basically:

```
<< listLists(Language)
>> ["niceGreetings", "referToSelf", "referToCollective", etc.]
```

It pretty much has to be compatible between Python 2 and 3, but I am a little flexible on that

Comment: You could try something like  `print([x for x in dir(Language) if not x.startswith("__")])`... but what do you _need_ this for, in the first place? Maybe a dictionary would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `dir(Language)`.

Output:

```
['__doc__',
 '__module__',
 'directionNonSpecific',
 'niceGreetings',
 'referToCollective',
 'referToObject',
 'referToSelf',
 'travelPastTense']
```

You can filter the result as follows:

```
[field for field in dir(Language) if not field.startswith("__")]
```

Output:

```
['directionNonSpecific',
 'niceGreetings',
 'referToCollective',
 'referToObject',
 'referToSelf',
 'travelPastTense']
```

Comment: my output is actually `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'directionNonSpecific', 'niceGreetings', 'referToCollective', 'referToObject', 'referToSelf', 'travelPastTense']` for some reason

Comment: did you use the second line of code he put up?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of all attributes on an object and filter for listiness:

```
[v for v in Language.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, list)]
```